# Is there a way to move WPML scripts in footer?

Tags: jquery, performance, plugin-wpml

I found out that wpml force my jquery to load into header. (I already deregistered it and registered my own one).

Is there a way to move wpml script in footer?

Comment: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-load-wpml-scripts-in-footer/

Comment: first result on google, already read. I asked here because maybe I need more infos or maybe I'd like to find different approach?

Comment: Yep! I deregister jquery, register it again with footer option 'true', but when I activate wpml main plugin, it forces jquery (and jquery ui) in the header. I'm going to search for wpml register script function, get scripts handles, deregister them in my theme and register them again with footer option.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. As commented on OP, WPML documentation and support are very minimal on this front.

I found that for me, the only culprit forcing jQuery to the head of the HTML was `wpml-xdomain-data.js` from `sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/url-handling/class-wpml-xdomain-data-parser.php:53`. This script appears to handle some part of the language switchers and, as I have a custom language switcher, I could deregister this script without loss of functionality:

`wp_deregister_script('wpml-xdomain-data');`

In `functions.php` through `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Also see: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-load-browser-redirect-js-and-jquery-cookie-js-in-the-footer/